# Is there a way to add a Cutoff Parameter to makeParamSet() for 'classif.rpart' trees in the mlr package?

Tags: parameters, decision-tree, hyperparameters, mlr

When making a parameter set for the randomForest model, I was able to use the following code to include cutoff values as parameters that are checked when doing a random search through the parameter space:

```
makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam('mtry', values = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
  
  ,
  makeDiscreteParam('ntree', values = seq(480,540, by = 10)),
  
  makeDiscreteParam('nodesize', values = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)),
  
  makeDiscreteParam("cutoff", values = list(
    a=c(.1,.9),
    b=c(.2,.8),
    c=c(.3,.7),
    d = c(.4, .6),
    e = c(.5,.5),
    f = c(.6,.4),
    g = c(.7,.3),
    h = c(.8,.2),
    i = c(.9,.1)
    
    ))
```

Is there a way to analagously do this for a 'classif.rpart' learner with type = 'prob'?

Thank you.

Comment: IIUC you want to use the `cutoff` parameter from RF in an rpart learner? You can also use the params defined for each learner. Also note that {mlr} is deprecated since more than two years and you might want to look into using {mlr3}.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I can't find a cutoff parameter defined for an rpart learner. Also, yes I know mlr3 is preferred, but mlr is the package I started learning hyperparameter tuning on, so I am going with it for now.

Comment: Every learner has different hyperparameters - mlr does not add any, we just mirror what the package supports.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is no equivalent hyperparameter for `rpart`. This is a limitation of the `rpart` package that `mlr` can't do anything about unfortunately.

Comment: Oh okay, is there an option for it with mlr3?

Comment: No, the underlying learner doesn't support it.